# Set an alias for a package in Android

Tags: android, package, alias

I have two classes with the same name but in different packages:

```
classA in mypackage.blabla.blabla.model
classA in mypackage.blabla.blabla.persistence
```

I need to refer to them from the same point:

```
mypackage.blabla.blabla.model.classA sample1 = new mypackage.blabla.blabla.model.classA();
mypackage.blabla.blabla.persistence.classA sample2 = new mypackage.blabla.blabla.persistence.classA();
```

Is it possible to set an alias for both packages in order to avoid typing so much?

for example:

```
alias for mypackage.blabla.blabla.model -> model
alias for mypackage.blabla.blabla.persistence -> persistence
```

so I would only have to type:

```
model.classA sample1 = new model.classA();
persistence.classA sample2 = new persistence.classA();
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such aliasing mechanism in Java.

You'll need to include at least one complete qualifier for one class or the other...

Comment: it says: Cannot resolve symbol 'model' when trying to import it using import mypackage.blabla.blabla.model same as with persistence.

Comment: Correct, my solution was not working with packages. You have no options but to include at least one full qualifier (limitations of Java, compared for example to Python).